# My Matlab program is not outputting the correct signal

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to output this signal on MATLAB and everything looks fine except for the dirac part. It is supposed to go straight up to y=2 at t=10 but it carries on horizontal. How can I fix this?

```
t=linspace(0,11,1101);

%create more than 500 time-series values

vs=exp(-4*(t-1)).*heaviside(t-1)+0.5*heaviside(t-5)+2*dirac(t-10);

%Input signal array

t1=linspace(0,22,2201);

plot(t,vs)

xlabel('t')

ylabel('v_s(t)')

title('Input signal')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signal goes to `Inf` at `t=10`, as expected. This is why you cannot see it in the plot (if you zoom in you should see a missing data point).

You can set the `Inf` value to a very high value (see the [docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/dirac.html#d117e64183)):

```
t=linspace(0,11,1101);
vs=exp(-4*(t-1)).*heaviside(t-1)+0.5*heaviside(t-5)+2*dirac(t-10);
vs(vs == Inf) = 100; % some high valueaxis limits
```

You can choose the value that it is visible as a sharp peak, but doesn't mess up your axis limits.